# GSON - need to know ExclusionStrategy in Custom serializer?

Tags: java, gson

Here's the setup. I have two different GSON instances each with a custom ExclusionStrategy. That allows me to represent an object differently depending on the GSON instance used. Think "Full Representation" vs. "Short Representation". If the object was a person, the short version might just spew first and last name while the full version would give lots of detail.

I also have custom serializers/deserializers registered. The problem is that the ExclusionStrategies aren't invoked for classes that use a custom serializer. I'd apply the Exclusion Strategy by hand, but I don't see any way of knowing, in my custom serializer, what Exclusion strategy should be in effect.

Any ideas?